# ¿Como puedo dar click a este botton utilizando selenium en python?

Tags: javascript, python, botón, selenium

Estoy intentado dar click al siguiente icono de una pagina.

```html
<div id="MasterBody_AnonymousTd" class="col-md-12 text-center" style="display:block;">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnAnonymous();">
                                        <i class="fa fa-user tpfa-1-5x tpNavyColor"></i>
                                        Anónimo
                                    </a>
                                </div>
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnAnonymous();">
                                        <i class="fa fa-user tpfa-1-5x tpNavyColor"></i>
                                        Anónimo
                                    </a>
```

Lo intente copiando el xpath asi:

```html
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MasterBody_AnonymousTd"]/a').click()
```

Y tambien con el selector de esta manera:

```html
WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
    .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                    '#MasterBody_AnonymousTd')))\
    .click()
```

Pero de ninguna de las dos maneras me genera el click sobre el icono, la parte visual del boton es la siguiente:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestra un poco mas del `html`. En tus ejemplo haces referencia a un `id`, pero en el `html` no lo muestras. Puedes intentar llegar a la etiqueta `<a>` como papá de `<i>` con clase `class="fa fa-user tpfa-1-5x tpNavyColor"`

Comment: Claro que si, ya edite mi pregunta, porfavor revisala

Comment: Puede que sea el `*` que pones en el xpath. Creo que no es necesario, con `//` te lleva al nodo mas interno. Por lo demás se ve bien

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto:

```
ejemplo = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MasterBody_AnonymousTd"]/a')

ejemplo.click()
```

o si esta ejecutando un archivo.robot puedes poner en una '***Task***' lo siguiente:

```
Click Element            //*[@id="MasterBody_AnonymousTd"]/a
```

Comment: Podrías editar tu respuesta y explicar que hacen los fragmentos de código que pusiste por favor? De ese modo aumentarás la calidad de tu respuesta, será mejor recibida y tanto el OP como otras personas que tengan el mismo problema podrían aprender algo nuevo. Además, Stack Overflow no es un repositorio de código.